# bash script remove squares prefix when reading a file content

Tags: shell, sh, gitlab-ci

I want to read a file using a bash script and I get a prefix of squares `□□`.
My question is why I get this squares and how I can remove them. Sry I am new to bash scripts. And thank you all for the help.

I have a file named `RELNOTES.md`

```markdown
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

## [1.0.20] - 2022-07-23

### Bug Fixes

- Release job description

### Documentation

- Add docs for changelog using git cliff

### Features

- Git cliff setup

<!-- generated by git-cliff -->
```

And a bash script to read the file

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "$(cat RELNOTES.md)"
```

When I run the command in bash terminal I get this output

```bash
sh scripts/print-release-notes.sh 
scripts/print-release-notes.sh: line 12: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
□□# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

## [1.0.20] - 2022-07-23

### Bug Fixes

- Release job description

### Documentation

- Add docs for changelog using git cliff

### Features

- Git cliff setup

<!-- generated by git-cliff -->
```

However I want this output.

```bash
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.

## [1.0.20] - 2022-07-23

### Bug Fixes

- Release job description

### Documentation

- Add docs for changelog using git cliff

### Features

- Git cliff setup

<!-- generated by git-cliff -->
```

### My question is

How to remove this squares `□□` <---------

Thank you all in advance

Comment: If you are reading a file from the Windows world it likely is encoded in UTF-16 with BOM (Byte Order Mark). Using `hexdump -Cv file` will allow you to look at the file in hex and determine what the offending characters are. See [Byte order mark - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. It was in UTF-16 by changing the encoding to UTF-8 I fix the issue. Many thanks @DavidC.Rankin